# Jmeter: Illegal character found in host: '/'

Tags: jmeter

I should send a `http GET` request `api.ionos.com/cloudapi/v5/images?depth=5` of course you cannot see any meaningful response since the request is not authorized.

But, currently the **jmeter is complaining because it found my request invalid** with the below error:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: Illegal character found in host: '/'
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.getUrl(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1231)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1220)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:622)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:546)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

So, here is the configuration of my test:

[image]

I put my:

Server Name or IP: `api.ionos.com/cloudapi/v5`
Path: `/images`

and then added a parameter `depth =5`

Why i am getting this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Server name is a hostname only, no path info, just like the message says

Try this:

Server Name or IP: `api.ionos.com` Path: `/images/cloudapi/v5/images`

You need to add a parameter named `depth` with a value of `5` (I'm pretty sure the `Parameters` tab you have selected will do exactly that.

Comment: it should finish with `images?depth=5`, but Yes. it solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

The correct [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler configuration would be:

[image]

it will result in the request you're looking for (can be validated using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener):

[image]

Going forward be aware that if you're uncertain regarding creating a HTTP Request sampler manually you can record it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html), [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium/) or create a test plan from [Curl command](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/curl.html)